# Node JS, Express & Pug Confusion - links / routes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I have Node.js, Express and Pug installed, and thought I was doing an MVC application. However, while I want my frontend pages to be (home, about, contact, login) with (snippets of data to connect to the backend) I can create these with pug (under views).

Wouldn't it be much faster to do these pages as static under my public folder with a stylesheet attached? Of course, I believe they would then need to be compiled into HTML for these to work I.

All I want to be able to do is create navigation that links these pages simply in pug, however, when running NPM I keep getting 404 errors (despite it working this morning).

If I can do this easily with pug, and just put a link, then why am I creating routes on the backend? Can someone please clarify this?

Pug (Sep nav file)

```
nav 
    a(href="/") Home
    a(href="about") Framework
    a(href="contact") Pricing
    a(href="login") Support
```

Express Routes

```
app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about");
});


app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});
```

app js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// View Engine ----------------------------
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about");
});


app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login");
});




// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I've used Django before and despite its MVT (its very similar) but a lot simpler I think and I was able to do e.g `%link%` to insert it into the HTML page.

Comment: It should probably be `a(href="/about")` just to be sure, but the version without the slash should also work, depending on what it says in your address bar. Speaking of which, what *does* it say in your address bar after you clicked a broken link? Also, yes, you can absolutely serve a bunch of static HTML files instead, provided express it set up properly. The idea of (pug) templates is primarily to insert dynamic data into them during the rendering. Example: `res.render("profile", { user: req.session.user })`

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for answering back. In the address bar, it just shows http://localhost:3000/about (despite still throwing the 404 error)

Comment: The route code itself looks fine, so the issue must be the rest of the code. Order is important; I assume you're calling `.listen()` *after* setting up the routes?

Comment: I've seen what you mean the .list(), belive its a call function, I've just added the app.js file (the majority of this came with the article I followed off express's website this morning) and I did wonder why this part wasn't in there.

Comment: I tested your code as-is, went to `localhost:3000/about` and can see the content of my `about.pug`